# Multiple problems with inline-block, text-align, and list-style HTML CSS

Tags: html, css, text, alignment

I have a few problems currently. I figure somewhere in my code I have something that is overriding my `display: inline-block` and `text-align:center`, along with the `list-style:none;` but I can't seem to figure out why it isn't working. I want the Home, About, and Contact lists in the header to not have bullets and to be in line, not stacked on each other. Also, I wanted the entire page centered. Thanks for any help I can get.

here is all of the html

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway: 300,400,700,900');
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}


/* header
    ============ */

header {
  /* position: absoulte; */
  margin-top: 1em;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1em;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img src="http://localhost:7879/img/logo.jpg" alt="Creative inc. logo" class="logo">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>

<section class="home-hero">
  <h1 class="title">Making things look great
    <span>for companies who make great stuff</span>
  </h1>
  <a href="#" class="button button-accent">See Our Work</a>
</section>


<section class="home-about">

  <div class="home-about-textbox">
    <h1>Who we are</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mel sanctus sensibus incorrupte at, ad homero aperiri duo, ad quo vidit impedit.</p>
    <p>Autem dolore in his. Essent everti appellantur te vel, cibo dignissim nam ex.</p>
  </div>

</section>


<section class="portfolio">
  <h1>Some of our work</h1>

  <!-- portfolio item 01 -->
  <figure class="port-item">
    <img src="" alt="portfolio item">
    <figcaption class="port-desc">
      <p>Project: title</p>
      <a href="#" class="button button-accent button-small">Project   details</a>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>

  <!-- portfolio item 02 -->
  <figure class="port-item">
    <img src="" alt="portfolio item">
    <figcaption class="port-desc">
      <p>Project: title</p>
      <a href="#" class="button button-accent button-small">Project details</a>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>

  <!-- portfolio item 03 -->
  <figure class="port-item">
    <img src="http://localhost:7879/img/portfolio-03.jpg" alt="portfolio item">
    <figcaption class="port-desc">
      <p>Project: title</p>
      <a href="#" class="button button-accent button-small">Project details</a>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>

  <!-- portfolio item 04 -->
  <figure class="port-item">
    <img src="http://localhost:7879/img/portfolio-04.jpg" alt="portfolio item">
    <figcaption class="port-desc">
      <p>Project: title</p>
      <a href="#" class="button button-accent button-small">Project details</a>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>

  <!-- portfolio item 05 -->
  <figure class="port-item">
    <img src="http://localhost:7879/img/portfolio-05.jpg" alt="portfolio item">
    <figcaption class="port-desc">
      <p>Project: title</p>
      <a href="#" class="button button-accent button-small">Project details</a>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>

  <!-- portfolio item 06 -->
  <figure class="port-item">
    <img src="http://localhost:7879/img/portfolio-06.jpg" alt="portfolio item">
    <figcaption class="port-desc">
      <p>Project: title</p>
      <a href="#" class="button button-accent button-small">Project details</a>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
</section>


<footer>

  <div class="col-3">

    <p>Per et tale ignota evertitur, vix ex inani dolore definiebas.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="col-1">
    <ul class="unstyled-list">
      <li><strong>Shoreditch</strong></li>
      <li>Shoreditch</li>
      <li>Woke retro</li>
      <li>Readymade</li>
      <li>Scenester</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="col-1">
    <ul class="unstyled-list">
      <li><strong>Shoreditch</strong></li>
      <li>Shoreditch</li>
      <li>Woke retro</li>
      <li>Readymade</li>
      <li>Scenester</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="col-1">
    <ul class="unstyled-list">
      <li><strong>Shoreditch</strong></li>
      <li>Shoreditch</li>
      <li>Woke retro</li>
      <li>Readymade</li>
      <li>Scenester</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</footer>
```

Comment: `display: inline-block`, `text-align:center` and `list-style:none;` everything is working fine.

Comment: Try adding `!important` on every rule to see if it works. If it does, you are right, you have some rules somewhere that overrides your desired styles. Try it in the inspector first. The snippet posted works just fine.

Comment: The snippet does work which is interesting. The tester I am using was not showing this result so maybe there is an issue with that. Thanks!